# Counting words in a collection using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have a StringCollection object with 5 words in them. 3 of them are duplicate words. I am trying to create a LINQ query that will count how many unique words are in the collection and output them to to the console. So, for example, if my StringCollection has 'House', 'Car', 'House','Dog', 'Cat', then it should output like this:

```
House --> 2
Car --> 1
Dog --> 1
Cat --> 1
```

Any ideas on how to create a LINQ query to do this?

Comment: How do you want to handle casing?

Comment: Ignore Case. Cat and cat should be treated as the same word

Comment: All your answers are great except I don't seem to have a .GroupBy method. Keep in mind that I am using a System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection object to store the strings, not a string array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: a method to count occurrences in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/c-a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following

```
var res = from word in col.Cast<string>()
          group word by word into g
          select new { Word = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: I believe a simple change to `group word by word.ToLower()` will fix that, of course all your keys will then be in lowercase.

Comment: To be fair his answer was probably written before that was added.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error. Keep in mind that I am using a System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection object to store the strings, not a string array

Comment: @icemanind i changed my answer to deal with the weakly typed collection.

Comment: @Taylor, my answer was written before the casing requirement was added.

Answer (score 4):

```
var xs = new StringCollection { "House", "Car", "House", "Dog", "Cat" };

foreach (var g in xs.Cast<string>()
                    .GroupBy(x => x, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", g.Key, g.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using StringCollection and want to ignore case, you'll need to use [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549140.aspx) with [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx):

```
var results = collection.Cast<string>.GroupBy(
        i => i,
        (word, words) => new { Word = word, Count = words.Count() },
        StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
    );

foreach(var wordPair in results)
     Console.WriteLine("Word: \"{0}\" - Count: {1}", wordPair.Word, wordPair.Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

To build a single string value result...

```
var stringCollection = new[] { "House", "Car", "house", "Dog", "Cat" };
var result = stringCollection.Cast<string>().GroupBy(
                                  k => k, 
                                  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                             .Select(v => v.Key + " -->" + v.Count())
                             .Aggregate((l,r)=>l+" " + r);
//result = "House -->2 Car -->1 Dog -->1 Cat -->1"
```

To put each value on a different line...

```
var stringCollection = new[] { "House", "Car", "house", "Dog", "Cat" };
var result = stringCollection.Cast<string>().GroupBy(
                                  k => k, 
                                  StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

foreach (var value in result)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value.Key, value.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var g in input.GroupBy(i => i.ToLower()).Select(i => new {Word = i.Key, Count = i.Count()})
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} -> {1}", g.Word, g.Count));
}
```

Comment: No! Using ToLower for case-insensitive string comparison == facefalm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
Console.WriteLine(stringCollection.Distinct().Count());
```

Comment: That will show the unique strings, but not the count of duplicated ones.

Comment: This will count the number of unique strings.  so it would return `4`

Comment: @Ray & @Matthew: Yes, the OP asked how to count how many unique words there are. Now that the example has been formatted, I realise that this is not what the OP intended to ask for...

Answer (score 0):

```
var query =    
  from s in Collection  
  group s by s.Description into g  
  select new {word = g.Key, num = g.Count()};
```