# Count the occurrence of strings in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, count

I am counting the how many strings are present in the array-

```
Tags = "the cat the mat the sat";

string[] words = Tags.Split(' ');

int counter = 0;

foreach (string item in words)
{
    if (item != "")
    {
      counter++;

    }
}
```

However how could I modify my code so that I counted the occurrence of every string.
So for instance -

- "the" = 3
- "cat" = 1
- "mat" = 1
- "sat" = 1

and then store these values some way?

Comment: Whole words only? For instance should "there" match "the"?

Comment: This question might be of interest also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026571/counting-words-in-a-collection-using-linq

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't say what language you use, but what I see it looks like c#. Here is one way to do it.

```
    Dictionary<string, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        if (dictionary.ContainsKey(word))
        {
            dictionary[word] += 1; 
        }
        else
        {
            dictionary.Add(word,1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var result = tags.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .GroupBy(tag => tag)
                 .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());
```

---

```
var max = result.MaxBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
var min = result.MinBy(kvp => kvp.Value);
```

using MaxBy and MinBy from [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Comment: I apologise I have just realised I accepted the wrong answer. This is the correct one.

Comment: giZm0's  answer is equally correct, just using a different style (one which matches the style of the code in your question). Since you explicitly asked for a modification of your code, I'd  consider giZm0's answer more correct than mine, but of course it depends on you which answer solves your problem best  :-)

Comment: ok i have changed again! @dtb I have still used your answer though as it did seem a bit more efficient. I am curious as to how I could work out the max and min values using your technique?

Comment: @dtb Nice solution. Always nice with "one liners"

Comment: i appreciate both your help, it was honest of you to suggest using @giZmo 's answer.

Comment: @dtb I have installed that package but it does not seem to be picking it up in the project do I need to reference it somewhere???

Comment: @dtb I wasnt referencing it, now works a treat, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Store in a map where the key is the word and the value is a counter of how many times it appears....

Answer (score 0):

You must use Dictionary. Here it is:

```
        string Tags = "the cat the mat the sat";

        string[] words = Tags.Split(' ');

        Dictionary<string, int> oddw = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (string item in words)
        {
            if (item != "")
            {
                if (oddw.ContainsKey(item) == false)
                {
                    oddw.Add(item, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    oddw[item]++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in oddw)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```