# How to let users add settings to My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, browser, settings, vb.net-2010

I actually have two questions here. First one is exactly what the title says. Example: I want users to be able to add a setting into My.Settings from the application. I want them to be able to add an unlimited amount and I want the scope to be set to user and the type set to string. I don't want them to be able to change the scope or type, only the "Title" and "Value". What I need this for is so users can make a setting so if they type "sof" into the URL bar of a VB.net browser it will go to "stackoverflow.com" of course I want them to be able to change the shortcut and the site and add new ones. I also want them to be able to view a list of all of them and edit or delete the ones on the list.

Second question is how do I make the code search through all of my settings and see if any of them are titled what the person put into the URL bar and if there is get the value of it and navigate too it.

I know this is a lot to ask, and I am not asking for someone to do it for me, I am asking someone what procedure would I follow to do this. If there is already a tutorial or an answer to this please link me to it. If you have the time please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, not to make Douglas look bad, but you can easily do what you want with the user settings. See this [My.Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saa62613.aspx) page from MS.  What you will want is the "System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection" setting type. The link I gave you shows you how to read, change, and save the data. It also shows you how to make a simple UI for the user to be able to change them, if you want.

As for the second part, also easy using LINQ. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3026571/counting-words-in-a-collection-using-linq) is not exactly what you want but it is close and has a lot of good examples.

Comment: Way to make me look bad!  I had no idea that you could save anything other strings in `My.Settings`.  I still don't think it's the best solution for this problem, but it is a simple one.  You get an upvote.

Comment: Not, not the best, just the answer to the question.