# How to display how many times an array element appears

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C# and hope I can get some help on this topic. I have an array with elements and I need to display how many times every item appears.

For instance, in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3]`, `1` appears one time, `4` appears three times, and so on.

I have done the following but don`t know how to put it in the foreach/if statement...

```
int[] List = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3};
foreach(int d in List)
{
    if("here I want to check for the elements")
}
```

Thanks you, and sorry if this is a very basic one...

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: nope it is not, I am just learning and trying to do so :-)

Comment: Try using a `Dictionary<int, int>` where each key represents a unique entry, and the value represents a count.  Each time you hit an existing key, increment its value by 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: a method to count occurrences in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/c-a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can handle this via [Enumerable.GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx).  I recommend looking at the [C# LINQ samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b) section on Count and GroupBy for guidance.

In your case, this can be:

```
int[] values = new []{1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3};

var groups = values.GroupBy(v => v);
foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("Value {0} has {1} items", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can keep a `Dictionary` of items found as well as their associated counts.  In the example below, `dict[d]` refers to an element by its value.  For example `d = 4`.

```
int[] List = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3};
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
foreach(int d in List)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(d))
        dict[d]++;
    else
        dict.Add(d, 1);
}
```

When the `foreach` loop terminates you'll have one entry per unique value in `dict`.  You can get the count of each item by accessing `dict[d]`, where `d` is some integer value from your original list.

Answer (score 3):

The LINQ answers are nice, but if you're trying to do it yourself:

```
int[] numberFound = new int[6];
int[] List = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3 };
foreach (int d in List)
{
    numberFound[d]++;
}
```

Comment: Why did you allocate 6 spaces for numberFound but only really have 5?

Comment: @JonH So that numberFound[x] will correspond to x, not to x-1. (numberFound will range from **0** to 5.)

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4, 3 };
var groups = list.GroupBy(i => i).Select(i => new { Number = i.Key, Count = i.Count() });
```

Answer (score -1):

private static void CalculateNumberOfOccurenceSingleLoop()

{

```
        int[] intergernumberArrays = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2 };

        Dictionary<int, int> NumberOccurence = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < intergernumberArrays.Length; i++)
        {
            if (NumberOccurence.ContainsKey(intergernumberArrays[i]))
            {
                var KeyValue = NumberOccurence.Where(j => j.Key == intergernumberArrays[i]).FirstOrDefault().Value;
                NumberOccurence[intergernumberArrays[i]] = KeyValue + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                NumberOccurence.Add(intergernumberArrays[i], 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> item in NumberOccurence)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: This is the same concept as [@Yuck's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11850986/150605) from 4.5 years ago, except that solution accesses each array element exactly once and this one iterates through the remainder of the array every time a new value is encountered.  Also, what is the purpose of retrieving an array element of type `int`, formatting it as a `string`, then parsing it back to an `int`?  Why not just use `intergernumberArrays[i]` instead of `int.Parse(intergernumberArrays[i].ToString())`?