# How do I find duplicates in an array and display how many times they occurred?

Tags: c#, arrays, duplicates

I'm working on a code that prints out duplicated integers from an array with the number of their occurrence. I'm not allowed to use LINQ, just a simple code. I think I'm so close but confused about how to get a correct output:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {              
        int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < array.Length - 1 ; j++)
            {

               if(array[j] == array[j+1])
                  count = count + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + "occurse" + count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since you can't use LINQ, you can do this with collections and loops instead:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{              
    int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    
    foreach(var value in array)
    {
        // When the key is not found, "count" will be initialized to 0
        dict.TryGetValue(value, out int count);
        dict[value] = count + 1;
    }
    
    foreach(var pair in dict)
        Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times.", pair.Key, pair.Value);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't ordinarily edit code in a post, but I think that the `TryGetValue()` pattern is so much more readable, as well as being more efficient (for the read, only one key lookup for values that are present rather than two), that I've gone ahead and made the edit instead of just proposing it. Feel free to revert if you really hate it.

Answer (score 25):

Use [Group by:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850935/how-to-display-how-many-times-an-array-element-appears)

```
int[] values = new []{1,2,3,4,5,4,4,3};

var groups = values.GroupBy(v => v);
foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("Value {0} has {1} items", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's take a look at a simpler example.  Let's say we have the array `{0, 0, 0, 0}`.

What will your code do?

It will first look to see how many items after the first item are equal to it.  There are three items after the first that are equal to it.

Then it goes to the next item, and looks for all items after it that are equal to it.  There are two.  So far we're at 5, and we haven't even finished yet (we have one more to add), but there are only four items in the whole array.

Clearly we have an issue here.  We need to ensure that when we've searched the array for duplicates of a given item that we don't search through it again for that same item.  While there are ways of doing that, this fundamental approach is looking to be quite a lot of work.

Of course, there are different approaches entirely that we can take.  Rather that going through each item and searching for others like it, we can loop through the array *once*, and add to a count of number of times we've found that character.  The use of a `Dictionary` makes this easy:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (int n in array)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(n))
        dictionary[n] = 0;
    dictionary[n]++;
}
```

Now we can just loop through the dictionary and see which values were found more than once:

```
foreach(var pair in dictionary)
    if(pair.Value > 1)
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
```

This makes the code clear to read, obviously correct, and (as a bonus) quite a lot more efficient than your code, as you can avoid looping through the collection multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an answer that avoids using Dictionaries. Since the OP said he is not familiar with them, this might give him a little insight into what Dictionaries do.

The downside to this answer is you have to enforce a limit on the max number in the array, and you can't have negative numbers. You'd never actually use this version in real code.

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
int[] count = new int[13];

foreach(int number in array) {
    // using the index of count same way you'd use a key in a dictionary
    count[number]++;
}

foreach(int c in count) {
    int numberCount = count[c];
    if(numberCount > 0) {
        Console.WriteLine(c + " occurs " + numberCount + " times");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] arr = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
var result = arr.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new { key = x.Key, val = x.Count() });       
foreach (var item in result)
{
    if(item.val > 1)
    {                
        Console.WriteLine("Duplicate value : {0}", item.key);
        Console.WriteLine("MaxCount : {0}", item.val);
    }

}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I have modified your code. This should do the job:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {

                if (array[i] == array[j])
                    count = count + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + " occurs " + count + " times");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will report "10 occurs 2 times" twice though.

Comment: That is right ,it sorts of working except for it prints out some values and their occurance more than one time.

Comment: Yes, that's what happens in this example. To get rid of it, you either need to use another array variable or a Dictionary as shown in other examples. But I didn't use any other variable other than you already used in your example.

Comment: I will go through it again ,but thank you for pushing it to this point :)

Answer (score 1):

/*This is the answer that helps you to find the duplicate integer values using Forloop and it will return only the repeated values apart from its times of occurences*/

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Array list to store all the duplicate values
        int[] ary = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
        ArrayList dup = new ArrayList();

        for (int i = 0; i < ary.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < ary.Length; j++)
            {
                if (ary[i].Equals(ary[j]))
                {
                    if (!dup.Contains(ary[i]))
                    {
                        dup.Add(ary[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The numbers which duplicates are");
        DisplayArray(dup);
    }
    public static void DisplayArray(ArrayList ary)
    {
        //loop through all the elements
        for (int i = 0; i < ary.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(ary[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void FindRepeating(int[] input) 
{
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        var abs = Math.Abs(input[i]);

        if (input[abs] >= 0)
            input[abs] = -input[abs];
        else
            Console.Write(abs + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a minor mistake of using J instead of i ...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {              
        int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < array.Length - 1 ; j++)
            {
               if(array[i] == array[j+1])
                  count = count + 1;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + "occurse" + count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 9, 7, 12, 12 };
Dictionary<int, int> duplicateNumbers = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int count=1;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    count=1;
    if(!duplicateNumbers.ContainsKey(array[i]))
    {
        for (int j = i; j < array.Length-1; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] == array[j+1])
            {
                count++;                            
            }
        }
        if (count > 1)
        {
            duplicateNumbers.Add(array[i], count);
        }
    }
}
foreach (var num in duplicateNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicate numbers, NUMBER-{0}, OCCURRENCE- {1}",num.Key,num.Value);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use a dictionary, you might as well use it _correctly_ and avoid the O(n^2) cost that the question's author has in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// How do you find the duplicate number on a given integer array?
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };

            Dictionary<int, int> duplicates = FindDuplicate(array);

            Display(duplicates);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static Dictionary<T, int> FindDuplicate<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
        {
            HashSet<T> set = new HashSet<T>();
            Dictionary<T, int> duplicates = new Dictionary<T, int>();

            foreach (var item in source)
            {
                if (!set.Add(item))
                {
                    if (duplicates.ContainsKey(item))
                    {
                        duplicates[item]++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        duplicates.Add(item, 2);
                    }
                }
            }

            return duplicates;
        }

        private static void Display(Dictionary<int, int> duplicates)
        {
            foreach (var item in duplicates)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}:{item.Value}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 4 };

```
    var duplicates = arr.GroupBy(x => x)
          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
          .Select(y => new { Item = y.Key, Count = y.Count() })
          .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(String.Join("\n", duplicates));
```

Answer (score -1):

This approach, fixed up, will give the correct output (it's highly inefficient, but that's not a problem unless you're scaling up dramatically.)

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length ; j++)
    {
       if(array[i] == array[j])
          count = count + 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + " occurs " + count);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I counted 5 errors in the OP code, noted below.

```
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
int count = 1;                                   // 1. have to put "count" in the inner loop so it gets reset
                                                 // 2. have to start count at 0
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < array.Length - 1 ; j++)  // 3. have to cover the entire loop
                                                 // for (int j=0 ; j<array.Length ; j++)
    {
       if(array[j] == array[j+1])                // 4. compare outer to inner loop values
                                                 // if (array[i] == array[j])
          count = count + 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + array[i] + "occurse" + count);
                                                 // 5. It's spelled "occurs" :)
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Edit**

For a better approach, use a `Dictionary` to keep track of the counts.  This allows you to loop through the array just once, and doesn't print duplicate counts to the console.

```
var counts = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int[] array = { 10, 5, 10, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 12 };
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    int currentVal = array[i];
    if (counts.ContainsKey(currentVal))
        counts[currentVal]++;
    else
        counts[currentVal] = 1;
}
foreach (var kvp in counts)
    Console.WriteLine("\t\n " + kvp.Key + " occurs " + kvp.Value);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 12 };
        List<int> nums = new List<int>();
        List<int> count = new List<int>();
        nums.Add(arr[0]);
        count.Add(1);
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {

            if(nums.Contains(arr[i]))
            {
                count[nums.IndexOf(arr[i])] += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                nums.Add(arr[i]);
                count.Add(1);
            }
        }

        for(int x =0; x<nums.Count;x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("number:"+nums[x] +"Count :"+ count[x]);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```