# C# - I need an Algorithm for the most repeated number in an algorithm

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

This is what I came up with and it doesn't work:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr =Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray<int>();
        int MostRepatedNumber = 0;
        int Count = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arr.Length -1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] == arr[i + 1])
            {
                Count++;
                MostRepatedNumber = arr[i];                            
            }


        } 
        if(arr[i] < arr.Length - 2)
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            {
                Count = 1;
                MostRepatedNumber = arr[i + 1];
            }          
         }  
        Console.WriteLine(MostRepatedNumber);
    }
```

Comment: An explanation too would be nice.

Comment: I have a mistake in the title it should be:
C# - I need an Algorithm for the most repeated number in an array.
I'm net to here, so I have no idea how I can edit it.

Comment: Below the tags in your question is an edit button, you can use that freely to make edits on your own question... What does "doesn't work" entail?

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<int, int>` to count how often each number appears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding duplicate integers in an array and display how many times they occurred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765589/finding-duplicate-integers-in-an-array-and-display-how-many-times-they-occurred)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the most repeated number in a list/array, you can group by the number, order descending by count, and take the first one in the ordered sequence:

```
IList<int> myNumbers = ...

int mostRepeated = myNumbers.GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .First()
    .Key;
```

This of course assumes you're only interested in one value.

---

If for some reason you don't want to use LINQ queries, you can do it the old-fashioned way with a single loop and `Dictionary` to keep track of counts:

```
static T MostRepeatedElement<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence)
{
    //a dictionary to hold the count of each element as we come across it
    Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>();

    //keep track of the currently found most-repeated count and value
    int maxCount = -1;
    T maxValue = default(T);

    foreach(var x in sequence)
    {
        //increment the count of elements seen with value "x"
        if (counts.ContainsKey(x))
            counts[x]++;
        else
            counts[x] = 1;

        //compare what we have with the current local maximum
        if (counts[x] > maxCount)
        {
            //the element "x" is a currently the most-repeated, save it
            maxCount = counts[x];
            maxValue = x;
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
}
```

Comment: I know this a way to do it, but I want to do it with an alorithm.

Comment: @rattlehead Define "algorithm"

Comment: Well, a math-like algorithm, not revolving around using the built-in functions and commands, with only loops and such.Sorry, but I'm new to programming, so I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray<int>();
            int max = 0;
            int mostRepeated = arr[0];
            foreach(int element in arr)
            {
                int[] temp = arr.Where(i => i == element).ToArray();
                if(temp.Length > max)
                {
                    max = temp.Length;
                    mostRepeated = element;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(mostRepeated);
        }
```