# Need to find recurring values in array between two bounds

Tags: c#, arrays, windows

I have this code to find recurring values in my array. I have 81 textboxs forming a grid, and they are in 9 rows of 9 boxes. I earlier on in my code saved them all to a one dimensional array with 81 elements. I found some of this code on another question: [Finding duplicate integers in an array and display how many times they occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20765589/finding-duplicate-integers-in-an-array-and-display-how-many-times-they-occurred), and it worked for me, but I cannot find which array element it actually was that recurred.

```
int[] OrigValues = new int[];//Already defined earlier, and assigned.

for (int c = 1; c <= 9; c++) //in this case, I called my int c instead of the usual i
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Row {0}:", c);
        var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        foreach (var value in OrigValues.SubArray(c * 9 -9, 9))
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
                dict[value]++;
            else
                dict[value] = 1;       
        }                        

        foreach (var pair in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times.", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            if (pair.Value >= 2 && pair.Key != 0)
            {
                //I have no way of finding which 2 array slots were the ones that had the same value in each of these rows.
            }
        }

    }
```

OrigValues.SubArray is an extension method, that works like substring, except it is for arrays, taking array element starting at an index, and going for a length(there, c* 9 - 9 is my index, and 9 is my length)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn this entire process into a LINQ query:

```
var duplicates =
    OrigValues
        .Select((value, index) => new
            {
                Coordinate = index,
                Value = value
            })
        .GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Value)
        .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
        .ToList();

foreach (var group in duplicates)
{
    Console.Write($"{group.Key} appears in");
    foreach (var tuple in group)
        Console.Write($" {tuple.Coordinate}");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: I wanted it to return to a value of 1-81, not with coordinates. So instead of writing (3 6) in the console, I wanted it to write 29

Comment: @ThatGuy Changed the code to only print the array indexes that contain duplicate values.

Comment: Thanks for the response with this,but getting error: "Cannot convert type '<anonymous type: int Coordinate, ushort Value>' to 'int' " at the  foreach(var group in duplicates)

Comment: @ThatGuy Yes, sorry, I forgot it's anonymous type inside.

Comment: Still having trouble... sorry iv'e never used LINQ before.

Comment: Try now, I haven't changed it in all places the first time. Now it should use the tuple and group consistently.

Comment: getting values way off in console, values that are completely wrong. 9 appears in049
0 appears in123467910111....
1 appears in562
8 appears in81356
2 appears in1966
7 appears in235253
4 appears in303855
3 appears in397180

Comment: There are no spaces... Add a space when writing the coordinate.