# How do I count the occurrence of each unique element in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010

I have an array of zip codes.  How do I obtain a list of every unique zip code in the array, and then count how many times the unique zip code occurred in the array?

I saw this:

[A method to count occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/c-a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

I have a hunch this is the solution to my problem, but I don't really understand it.  Can someone please tell me if this is

1. indeed the best way to go about it.  And
2. show me how to put an array into a List so that I can take advantage of GroupBy?

Comment: Why don't you try? Besides that trying is learning, shorter than writing this question.

Comment: If it is unique the answer is always 1......... unless you meant distinct :)

Comment: Yes, I guess I mean distinct.  I'm still learning the terminology/syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
var zips = new string[] { "12345", "12345", "54321" };
var groups = zips.GroupBy(z => z);

foreach(var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Should give you:

```
12345 -> 2
54321 -> 1
```

driis actually gets you most of the way there. I just posted this to help show how to enumerate the groups.

Comment: It's just the format used for displaying the information. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx.

Comment: Let's say that instead of using Console.WriteLine I want to store the values into an array.  How do I do this?

Comment: @phan var zipArray = groups.Select(g => new { Zip = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToArray();

Answer (score 1):

You should use Where to only select entries with count == 1 and use Select to list the values and then ToList() to return a List.

It would be something like this:

```
List<string> uniqueZips = zips.GroupBy(z=>z).Where(z => z.Count() == 1).Select(z => z.Key).ToList();
```

Search for 101 linq examples on the internet, it gives you a lot of common examples.

Answer (score 0):

GroupBy works on `IEnumerable<T>`, and therefore also on an array (arrays implement IEnumerable). GroupBy groups objects based on a key. The key here is the zipcode itself; so you can just pass in a delegate that maps to that:

```
var zips  = new string []{"8000", "9000"}
var uniqueZips = zips.GroupBy(x => x);
```

Now, `uniqueZips` is an [`IGrouping<string,string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx), where the key is the zip code and the number of elements is the number of occurences of that zip code.

Comment: .Distinct() is possibly better to use than a .GroupBy(). The OP also wants the count in each group.

Comment: How would you get the count with Distinct ?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have only partially answered the question.