# Write frequency of numbers in one array into another

Tags: c#, arrays

I am writing a little app for statistics. A function of this app will be determining the frequency of randomly generated numbers in an `Array` which holds 100 elements.

So far, I managed to generate a two-dimensional `Array` which I have filled with the numbers 0-100 (these are max and min of randomly generated numbers in the other `Array`).

I thought of filling this array with the frequency based on the index.

Like this:

```
//Array for random numbers
int[] randomNumbers = new int[10] {2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 8, 9, 3, 7};

//Two-dimensional array for holding frequency of each unique number
int[,] frequency = new int[2,101];

for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    frequency[0, i] = i;
}
```

The frequency array gets generated fine. But I don't know where to go from here. How could I add the frequency of each unique number to the array? I tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.Length; i++)
{
    frequency[1, i] = frequency[1, i] + 1;
}
```

But it just fills the frequency array with ones continuously.

Comment: when you specify in tag which version of .net/c# you're using, it is easier to give better answer.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why? do arrays behave differently in different versions of .net?

Comment: @LeonidasFett I don't see how it'd be an issue here.  Perhaps if you were using a particularly old version of the language some of the library classes/tools that someone might want to use wouldn't be there (i.e. my answer is C# 3+).  Personally I don't see this question needing to specify a version unless you're using C# 1 or 2.

Comment: @LeonidasFett, in concrete case, Linq is not supported in 2.0 and older .net version, in other cases there may be new collection types, tools for multithreading, etc. And as long as 2.0 is fading away, it is not so mainstream anymore, but for example not many people are able to use 4.5 version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: a method to count occurrences in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/c-a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`GroupBy` makes this pretty straightforward.

```
var frequencies = randomNumbers.GroupBy(n => n)
    .Select(group => new 
             {
                Number = group.Key, 
                Frequency = group.Count() 
             });
```

Comment: thanks this works flawlessly, it even leaves out the numbers not present the random numbers array.

Answer (score 2):

You may find it useful to have two arrays, and each time you generate a random number, you would set the next element of the first array to the number, and set the random numberth element of the second array to itself +1. This will give you statistics from the start (from POV of the random number generator.

```
int[] vals, stats;

vals = new int[100]
stats = new int[100]

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    vals[i] = getRandom();
    stats[vals[i]] = stats[vals[i]] + 1;
}
```

Something like that might do the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
int[] randomNumbers = ...;
int[] frequency = new int[101];
for (int i = 0, l = randomNumbers.Length; i < l; ++i)
    ++frequency[randomNumbers[i]];
```

The result of this is that the `frequency` array contains the number of occurrences for each index. In other words `frequency[0]` will contain the number of occurrences of the value `0`, `frequency[1]` will contain the number of occurrences of the value `1`, etc...

Comment: This approach is also considerable faster than any LINQ-based approach. Cursory testing indicates this is about 10x faster than the GroupBy approach.

Comment: Note that I just posted an update to this code that changes it from a foreach to a for. This further improves performance.

Comment: @MichaelGunter It's 100 items; the performance will be much quicker than it needs to be regardless of the approach.  If he had a few billion items then perhaps speed would matter.  Oh, and also note that this approach *only* works for getting the frequency of integer types, whereas `GroupBy` will work for *any* type that implements `IEquatable`.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it that way, you have index in frequency table as value of number and actual value is frequency (just something like that not exactly):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    frequency[i] = randomNumbers.SelectMany( o=>o.ArrayProperty==i ).Count() ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To me, it looks like a `Dictionary<int, int>` is what's best suited to your needs:

```
Dictionary<int, int> frequency = new Dictionary<int, int>();

foreach (int number in randomNumbers)
{
    if (frequency.ContainsKey(number))
        frequency[number]++;
    else
        frequency.Add(number, 1);
}

int numberOfGroups = frequency.Count;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this:

```
int[] randomNumbers = new int[10] {2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 2, 8, 9, 3, 7};

Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int,int>();

foreach(int randomNumber in randomNumbers)
{
    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(randomNumber))
        dictionary.Add(randomNumber, 1);
    else
        dictionary[randomNumber]++;
}
```

If you then want to sort them, use Linq...

```
var sortedList = from pair in dictionary
    orderby pair.Key
    select pair;
```