# How to go through an array and create a list to count the number of times a number is repeated

Tags: c#, arrays, list, replace, tuples

friends of the forum.

First of all I apologize for my English

How to go through an array and create a list to count the number of times a number is repeated and sorted by item2 from highest to lowest.

I have the following array:

```
int[] arrayNumeros= new int[10] {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3}
```

I have the following List:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> contadorNumerosTotal = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
```

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumeros.Length; i++)
    {
         if (contadorNumerosTotal.Any(t => t.Item1 == arrayNumeros[i]))                    
         {
             //if the number exists I want item2 to be incremented by 1.
         }else{
              contadorNumerosTotal.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(arrayNumeros[i], 1));
         }
}



    for (int i = 0; i < contadorNumerosTotal.Count; i++)
    {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(contadorNumerosTotal[i].Item1 +" -> "+ contadorNumerosTotal[i].Item2);                   
    }
```

As a result it should show:

```
1 -> 3
3 -> 3
2 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 1
6 -> 1
```

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Use Linq GroupBy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A method to count occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)

Comment: could look at use linear search algorithm if your goal is just to find repeated elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should produce the desired results:

```
int[] numbers = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3};

Dictionary<int, int> numberCount = new Dictionary<int, int>();

int len = numbers.Length;
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (numberCount.ContainsKey(numbers[i]))
    {
        numberCount[numbers[i]]++;
    }
    else
    {
        numberCount[numbers[i]] = 1;
    }
}

// Sort by value if necessary. Otherwise loop through numberCount.
var sortednumberCount = numberCount.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value);
foreach (var number in sortednumberCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", number.Key, number.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 1
6 -> 1
```

Comment: Many thanks Tristan Gibson. It was what I needed.
A greeting.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> contadorNumerosTotal =
    arrayNumeros.GroupBy (i => i).Select (ints => new Tuple<int, int> (ints.Key, ints.Count ())).ToList ();
contadorNumerosTotal.Sort ((tuple, tuple1) => tuple1.Item2.CompareTo (tuple.Item2));
```

This takes the elements, groups `arrayNumeros` by the value of the numbers and transforms the list, so that it contains the value (this is the key of the group) and the count of the value (this is the count of the group). Lastly it sorts the elements of the list descending from the count (You could sort it ascending by comparing the Item2 of `tuple` to the Item2 of `tuple1` instead of the other way round.

You could print the results like this:

```
int [] arrayNumeros = new int[10] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 2, 3};
List<Tuple<int, int>> contadorNumerosTotal =
    arrayNumeros.GroupBy (i => i).Select (ints => new Tuple<int, int> (ints.Key, ints.Count ())).ToList ();
contadorNumerosTotal.Sort ((tuple, tuple1) => tuple1.Item2.CompareTo (tuple.Item2));
foreach (var count in contadorNumerosTotal)
    Console.WriteLine ($"{count.Item1} -> {count.Item2}");
Console.ReadLine ();
```

Which results in the following:

```
1 -> 3
2 -> 2
3 -> 2
4 -> 1
5 -> 1
6 -> 1
```

Read more about `groupBy` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arrayNumeros= new int[10] {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,2,3};

var result = arrayNumeros
    .GroupBy( e => e )
    .ToDictionary( e => e.Key, e => e.Count() )
    .OrderByDescending( e => e.Value )
    .ThenBy( e => e.Key )
    .Select( e => Tuple.Create( e.Key, e.Value ) )
    .ToList();
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vdpxqn)

Comment: This however has another type than he wanted. And, btw an explanation doesn't hurt either.