# C# Count occurrences in List Dynamically

Tags: c#, list

I have a `List<String> Fruits` that stores a list of fruits the user enters.

For example `Fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Apple", "Orange"}`

I would like to count the number of occurrences of each fruit.

How do I go about this?
I come from a python background, and to solve this I would use dictionary. Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `GroupBy()` and `Count()` each group's results

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list Similar to maccettura answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may GroupBy the friuit name and take count of each group:

```
Fruits.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => new {Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count()});
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhUkyH)

Answer (score 1):

Utilise `GroupBy` followed with `ToDictionary`:

```
Dictionary<string, int> result = fruits.GroupBy(x => x)
                                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```