# Counting elements with same pattern from a C# list object

Tags: c#, list, linq, count

Hi I have a C# list object that contains employee data from my sql table. Now there is a column name BadgeNumber which has either 6 character or 13 character string values. I need the count of all the 6 char and 13 char badges.

I used foreach loop to get the count and it is working fine. But I was wondering if there is any faster solution to this?

Below is my current implementation.

```
var empDetails = GetAllEmployeeDetails();

int internalEmpCount;
int contractEmpCount;

foreach (var emp in empDetails)
{
    if (emp.BadgeNumber.Length == 6)
        internalEmpCount++;
    else if (emp.BadgeNumber.Length == 13)
        contractEmpCount++;
}
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", internalEmpCount, contractEmpCount);
```

I looked at this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list) but that is more about duplicate values and thus I don't think I can use group by here as in my case all the badge numbers are unique and only similarity is the length of badge numbers. But any suggestions or comments are appreciated!

Comment: Better as in how? You could get a linq solution but I wouldn't necessary say it's better

Comment: Can you define what's "better" for you? Less code? Faster execution? What is it?

Comment: I don't see any issues with this approach. O(n) to get your counts.

Comment: If BadgeNumber only has either 6 character or 13 character values, the second if statement is not required. Then you only need count one & calculate the other from the total details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: @Naphstor that is the fastest solution. There are more explicit and more readable version but they will all end up being slower

Comment: What is the type of empDetails variable? Is it an array?

Comment: this is as fast as it gets.. You have to iterate all items (unless already sorted by length previously).. Just as pointed out - else if can just be else

Comment: @MihailShishkov it is a List<> object with sql table data in it.

Comment: Speedup can be achieved here if empDetails is an array and you use for loop instead of foreach.

Comment: for loop on a List is also faster than foreach but array beats them all

Comment: Anyway you can do it A LOT more faster if you let the DB do this for you. Something like SELECT LENGTH(Emp.BadgeNumber), COUNT(1) FROM Emp GROUP BY LENGTH(Emp.BadgeNumber)

Comment: Have in mind that you'll notice the difference only if you have thousands of employees. There is an anti thing called "Premature Optimization" go check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code enumerates your sequence exactly once. To calculate the requested values, the complete sequence needs to be enumerated. Hence you, nor LINQ can't get it more efficient.

The only efficiency you can have is by replacing your two if statements with one switch statement. This way property length will be evaluated only once:

```
switch (emp.BadgeNumber.Length)
{
    case 6:
        internalEmpCount++;
        break;
    case 13:)
        contractEmpCount++;
        break;
    // default: do nothing
}
```

Or, if you are absolutely certain that the length is either 6 or 13:

```
if (emp.BadgeNumber.Length == 6)
    internalEmpCount++;
else
    contractEmpCount++;
```

### More efficiency: Let your database do the counting

One of the slower parts of a database query is the transport of the selected data from the DBMS to your local process. Hence it is wise to limit the amount of transported data.

**If the only reason for your list is counting the elements,** consider to let your database do the counting and transport only the end result instead of the complete list.

```
IQueryable<EmpDetail> empDetails = ...

var result = empDetails
    // keep only the empDetail that you want to count:
    .Where(empDetail => empDetail.BadgeNumber.Length == 6
                     || empDetail.BadgeNumber.Length == 13)

    // make groups with same BadgeNumber.Length:
    .GroupBy(empDetail => empDetail.BadgeNumber.Length,

         // ResultSelector:
         (length, empDetailsWithThisLength) => new
         {
             Length = length,
             Count = empDetailsWithThisLength.Count,
         });
```

Result: a collection of two items, each with [Length, Count]. So only 4 integers will be transported.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is okay. *However* you do not require the 13 length limit check. This is only if you have input validation. You may change it to an else speeding up execution marginally.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I will probably have a condition in case of 13 chars to further filter down the badge numbers so that is why I kept else if. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also group by the badgenumber *length*. If you rurn the result to a dictionary, you can easily get your required values out.

```
var empDetails = GetAllEmployeeDetails();
var result = empDetails.GroupBy(x => x.BadgeNumber.Length)
                       .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Count());
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", result[6], result[13]);
```

Note this is *not* faster, *not* more efficient, and *not* any more readable than your solution!

Comment: @GiladGreen it explicitly *isnt*