# How to get unique duplicate values from an list object c#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get unique duplicated values from a list object.
I have tried the following and I get an error to rewrite my query.
I am not sure if it is an EF limitation or I am overlooking some issue.
My Goal is to return unique duplicates from a list OBJECT that contain mixed records some of which are duplicates.

```
var UniqueDuplicates = MYList()
      .GroupBy(i => new { i.item })
      .Where(i => i.Count() > 1)
      .SelectMany(x => x)
      .OrderBy(i => i.SubmittedOn)                                      
      .ToList();
```

```
var people = new[]
{
    new {
            Name = "Vernon",Age = 24,Email = "Vernon@email.com",Phone = "806-291-8721",          
        },
    new {
            Name = "Carrie",Age = 24,Email = "Carrie@email.com",Phone = "617-389-2329",
            
        },
    new {
            Name = "Thomas",Age = 23, Email = "Thomas@email.com", Phone = "906-875-5259",
        }
    new{
            Name = "kerry",Age = 22, Email = "kerry@email.com", Phone = "906-875-5259",
        }
    new{
            Name = "Tim",Age = 23, Email = "Tim@email.com", Phone = "906-875-5259",
        }
    new{
            Name = "Neil",Age = 23, Email = "Neil@email.com", Phone = "906-875-5259",
        }
        
};
```

the below method return the unique count of duplicates for the value, in my list it will return 2

```
  var countduplicates = People().GroupBy(x => x.age).Count(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to have a list returned that contains the set of elements that appear more than once within a parent list? E.g. if you had List<T> = [a,b,c,a,b,d] you'd want [a,b] returned ?

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, indicate the actual problem you are observing, and the result you are expecting?

Comment: Could you provide *some examples*, please? "Unique duplicates" sounds quite unclear.

Comment: I just updated the post and provided an example, In the list provided, there are 3 unique ages {22,23,24} tow of them have  duplicates in the list, how can I search the list and  return only the unique duplicated values for age, basically only return {23,24 } because the have duplicate,  ignore {22} because it has no duplicates in the list/

Comment: It would be useful to define a "duplicate" here, what makes two objects equal? 2 objects with the same age are equal?

Comment: What is a "unique duplicate"? A duplicate that just occurs once? Then it'll get complicated ... ^^ Merry Christmas by the way

Comment: @user5711432: *"updated the post and provided an example"* - In this example, are we to assume that `MYList()` simply returns `people`?  What is `i.item`?  What is `i.SubmittedOn`?  Where do you check this `Age` property for duplication?  The question mentions an error, have you tried reading the error message?

Answer (score 1):

So you have a collection of `People`:

```
var people = new[] {
  new { Name = "Vernon", Age = 24, Email = "Vernon@email.com", Phone = "806-291-8721", },
  new { Name = "Carrie", Age = 24, Email = "Carrie@email.com", Phone = "617-389-2329", },
  new { Name = "Thomas", Age = 23, Email = "Thomas@email.com", Phone = "906-875-5259", },
  new { Name = "kerry",  Age = 22, Email = "kerry@email.com",  Phone = "906-875-5259", },
  new { Name = "Tim",    Age = 23, Email = "Tim@email.com",    Phone = "906-875-5259", },
  new { Name = "Neil",   Age = 23, Email = "Neil@email.com",   Phone = "906-875-5259", },
};
```

And you are grouping people by their `Age`, and so you have:

```
Age: 22, Count: 1
Age: 23, Count: 3
Age: 24, Count: 2
```

Finally, as I can see (correct me if I am not right), you want to get unique `Age`s with unique `Count` which is greater than `1`. We have **2** *distinct* `Counts` greater than `1` (these are `2` and `3`) so the answer is `{23, 24}`.

If it's your case, you can put it as:

```
var result = people
  .GroupBy(human => human.Age)
  .Select(group => (
     age   : group.Key, 
     count : group.Count())
   )
  .Where(item => item.count > 1)  // Duplicates only
  .DistinctBy(item => item.count) // .Net 6 option 
  .Select(item => item.age)       // We want just ages  
  .ToArray();                     // Let it be materialized as an array
```

If you have an old version of .Net / C#, you can use `GroupBy` + `First` instead of `DistinctBy`:

```
var result = people
  .GroupBy(human => human.Age)
  .Select(group => (
     age   : group.Key, 
     count : group.Count())
   )
  .Where(item => item.count > 1)  
  .GroupBy(item => item.count) 
  .Select(group => group.First().age) 
  .ToArray();
```

Please [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PnBc1v) yourself

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thank you for you response from your grouping, All i need is the unique values that are duplicated, not their count basically return{23,24}, hope this helps.

Comment: @user5711432: If you are looking for `Age`s, not `Count`s you can try `DistinctBy` instead of `Distinct`

Comment: I am getting an error saying , an expression tree may not contain a tuple literal.

Comment: @user5711432: please, fiddle yourself: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PnBc1v

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method* that can return the count of appearances of an object within a list, something like this could do the trick (partly pseudocode):

```
private List<string> ReturnUniqueDuplicates(List<string> InputList)
        {
            List<string> Duplicates = new List<string>();
            foreach (string Element in InputList)
            {
                if (object appears more than once* and not in Duplicates ) { Duplicates.Add(Element); }
            }
            return Duplicates;
        }
```

However, if you're having trouble getting the count, it seems someone had a really nice solution to that here: [A method to count occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list)