# Get repeat elements in a list in c#

Tags: c#

I know this code is not optimal but I need help with a question about it, I am trying to obtain the number of times each element of the list is repeated, I do this by increasing the number found in that index by 1 in the `listIndexList`, as a copy of the algorithm of ordering by counting, but I have a problem and that is that if the element is repeated more than 1, you automatically see the number that must represent the number of times it is repeated, it goes crazy and gives me very rare numbers, if it is repeated 2 times it says that it is 4 and if it is repeated 3 times it says that it is 9.

This is the code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 10 };
List<int> listIndex = new List<int>();
int yts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if (list[i] > yts)
    {
        yts = list[i];
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i <= yts; i++)
{
    listIndex.Add(0);
}

for (int u = 0; u < list.Count; u++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        if (list[u] == list[j])

        {
            int num = list[u];
            listIndex[num] = listIndex[num] + 1;

        }
    }
}

foreach (int i in listIndex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

this is what i need

```
listIndex[0] = 0
listIndex[1] = 1
listIndex[2] = 0
listIndex[3] = 3
listIndex[4] = 0
listIndex[5] = 0
listIndex[6] = 2
listIndex[7] = 0
listIndex[8] = 0
listIndex[9] = 0
listIndex[10] = 1
```

And this is what I receive:

```
listIndex[0] = 0
listIndex[1] = 1
listIndex[2] = 0
listIndex[3] = 9
listIndex[4] = 0
listIndex[5] = 0
listIndex[6] = 4
listIndex[7] = 0
listIndex[8] = 0
listIndex[9] = 0
listIndex[10] = 1
```

Comment: Consider creating a `Dictionary<int, int>`. Whenever you get a number, use `Dictionary.TryGetValue` to see if it's in the dictionary (and, if it is, the current value). If the number is there, increment the current value, if it isn't, insert an entry, with the key equal to the  umber of interest and a value of `1`

Comment: Related: [A method to count occurrences in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139181/a-method-to-count-occurrences-in-a-list).

Comment: this is where debuggers come in handy

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ, this becomes pretty easy:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

The statement will create a `Dictionary<int,int>`, where the key is the number and the value is the amount of occurences in the list. We can just group by the integer values of the list and then create a dictionary with the key and the count of the groups.

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/39qgWu

Answer (score 1):

(I will just correct your original code rather than suggest alternative approaches)

The error is in your `for (int u = 0; u < list.Count; u++)` loop.

You have already initialised the `listIndex[]` list so that it contains a number of elements equal to the maximum value in `list` plus one. This is correct.

So all you need to do now is to iterate through the values in `list[]` and use each of those values as the index of the value in `listIndex[]` to increment.

Thus, all you need to do is to change your `for (int u = 0; u < list.Count; u++)` loop to the following:

```
for (int u = 0; u < list.Count; u++)
{
    ++listIndex[list[u]];
}
```

Notice how we are using `list[u]` as an index into `listIndex[]` and we increment the value at that index.

(As others have pointed out, this approach is inefficient in its use of memory if the maximum value in `list[]` is large, because it will require a list with length equal to that maximum value.)

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it without Linq, then sorting the list before the algorithm helps a lot. Then all numbers to find are next to each other and only one iteration is necessary. Something like this

```
    var list = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 10 };
    list.Sort();
    
    var listIndex = new List<int>() { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    
    int find = list[0];
    
    for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
      int start = i - 1;
      while (list[i] == find && i < list.Count) i++;
      
      int count = i - start;
      
      listIndex[find] = count;
      
      find = list[i];
      listIndex[find] = 1;
    }
```

Comment: No, there is no need to sort and using `List` to store the results is not a great idea, what if you have two elements, `int.MaxValue` and 1? Just use dictionary and update it while iterating the list, which would `O(n)` (assuming constant search time in dictionary in average/amortized case) compared to `O(n log n)`.

Comment: oh I agree that dictionary is better of course, but this looks like a program where the purpose is to learn to code an algorithm